# "Snub out a cigarette" for "stub out a cigarette" in AmEng

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

My bilingual dictionary marks "snub out” as an Americanism for “stub out” as in, “He snubbed out his cigarette.”

Is this phrasal verb common enough in present-day spoken AmEng that it can be used quite safely in general conversation?

Please consider [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stubbed+out+his%2Csnubbed+out+his%2Cstuffed+out+his&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstubbed%20out%20his%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnubbed%20out%20his%3B%2Cc0).

Since the primary meaning of snub is, “ignore, behave coldly toward; slight”, I would tend to think “snub out” might suggest a certain way to put out a cigarette or cigar.

Comment: I have only heard it as _"snuff out"_.

Comment: The most common thing I recall hearing is "put out"

Comment: @Tim Seguine: Per my answer, GB claims 89K hits for *stubbed out*. Apparently it only has 73K for *put out*, and that can cover present as well as past tense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't remember ever reading it or hearing it personally, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything. Just proposing a reasonable alternative. Judging by the ngram, not a bad one either.

Comment: @Tim: I take it you mean you don't remember coming across cigarettes being "snubbed out". I'd find it hard to believe you're not even *familiar* with "stubbed out" (but obviously it's possible you personally read/hear "put out" more often, even if that's a bit less common in the world at large).

Comment: @FumbleFingers As a programmer "stubbing something out" has a specific, unrelated jargon meaning, so it probably seems unnatural to me for that reason. Maybe I repressed it.

Comment: @Tim: I'd often refer to "stub functions" (containing no active code), or "comment stubs" (auto-generated comments that hopefully the programmer might flesh out later). But I never heard of "stubbing something out" - would that mean "converting all active code into comments", or what?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I have seen it in the sense of adding stub functions or stub methods to something. For example: we know what the unfinished interface should look like, and we want it to compile with code that uses the entire interface, so we "stub out" the missing functionality until we get a chance to write it properly.

Comment: While I have definitely heard/read "snubbed out", is suspect it's a conflation of "stubbed out" and "snuffed out". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snubbed+out+his+cigarette%2C+snuffed+out+his+cigarette%2C+stubbed+out+his+cigarette%2C+put+out+his+cigarette&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnubbed%20out%20his%20cigarette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnuffed%20out%20his%20cigarette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstubbed%20out%20his%20cigarette%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20out%20his%20cigarette%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I've ever heard *snub out* used of cigarettes, etc., but here are some counts of written instances in Google Books showing that it's certainly used (just not *that* often by comparison)...

> *snubbed out his cigarette* [3,150 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20have%20a%20doubt%20about%20this%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22snubbed%20out%20his%20cigarette%22&tbm=bks)
>    *snuffed out his cigarette* [7,490](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20have%20a%20doubt%20about%20this%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22snuffed%20out%20his%20cigarette%22&tbm=bks)
>    *stubbed out his cigarette* [89,200](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20have%20a%20doubt%20about%20this%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22stubbed%20out%20his%20cigarette%22&tbm=bks)

The problem for me is that I consider *snuffed out* to be a perfectly valid (if somewhat less common) usage. In my understanding, if you *snuff out* your cigarette, you *stop it burning* by pinching off the burning tip (also referred to as *dogging* it, in my vernacular). Alternatively, using liquid - spit, or a drop of wine transferred from a glass via your finger. But crucially, you can *relight it later, and smoke the rest of the cigarette*.

If *stub out* a cigarette, you've probably mashed it up so much there's no chance of smoking any tobacco that might have been left.

So I've no idea whether the (portmanteau? malapropism?) form *snub* leaves anything capable of being smoked later or not. If so, rather than being a blend of the two more common forms, it might relate to *snub* as in *snub-nosed* (***short*** and turned up). Perhaps the allusion is to *making a shorter cigarette to smoke later*.

Comment: Oh, yes. It gets used. There's a natural affinity.

Comment: @John: Ah, but *are you a smoker?* Specifically, one who is or has been at times impecunious? That's the crucial distinction available to me through the *snuff/stub* choice. Though as I recall, back in the real "bad old days" of being an impoverished student, I was more likely to say *"If you're only going to have a couple of puffs, don't stub it out! Dog it, and I'll have it later!"* to those of my fellow students who were ostentatiously/carelessly rich.

Comment: I used to be. I've heard both. There are phonosemantic reasons, btw.

Comment: @John: I take it by that you mean there are a number of words starting with "s" + consonant + "u", many of which share some common element of meaning. So even if we're not consciously aware of this, we favour the survival of words fitting that pattern. *Scud, scuff, stump,* etc., etc.

Comment: No, not really. More precisely, I mean that the [sn- assonance](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf) is compatible with both the -[əf rime](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/uff.txt) and [-əb rime](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/ub.txt), and that they're compatible with each other.

Comment: There's a [detailed description of -əb here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/rimecoherence.pdf); it's very popular and appears to be growing.

Comment: @John: Wow! that's fascinating! Do all serious linguists just know things like that for all the comparable "groupings" with statistical significance, or is it something you happen to be interested in? By which I mean I guess that **SN- 38/44 = 86%** must mean these are *measured characteristics*, not "armchair opinions" like mine. Have you guys *already* mapped all the "significant" instances of phonosemantics in action in English?

Comment: Several different ways. But it's mostly an interest of mine; I doubt I'll publish more on it. The data's there for anybody interested, and it's not particularly interesting for most linguists.

Comment: @John: oic. I sorta think of linguistic change as a bit like weather. So the more we understand current patterns, the better we might be able to predict the future. I'm sure to the professionals it must sound like I'm away with the fairies if I imagine anyone might see the future shape of a hypothetical global language. But that's the advantage of ignorance - you can *dream*, unfettered by conflicting information and practical considerations!

Answer (score 2):

***Stub it out*** is written on street cigarette bins, I saw it in Glasgow, Scotland. It is probably used only in UK, that's why people worldwide don't know what it means.

[image]

*Source: http://www.flickriver.com/*